# FFmpeg convert 1 JPEG frame to 10 sec video

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, script

I have a 952×600 JPEG image, generated by a PHP script. I want to create another PHP script that uses `ffmpeg`, which converts that JPEG image to a MP4 video, which has only 1 frame that lasts for 10 seconds.

Which options should I provide to FFmpeg, if the input JPEG is called `input.jpeg` and the video `output.mp4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
ffmpeg  -loop 1  -t 10  -i input.jpg  output.mp4
```

---

*The explanation and additions:*

Your input file (an image) will go through the default `image2` demuxer, which makes a video stream from it.

1. By default, this video stream will contain **only 1 frame** (the input picture), and its framerate will be **25 FPS** (frames per second), so the duration of this stream will be only 40 miliseconds (= 1/25 s).

   To repeat your input image for obtaining more frames, I used the options `-loop 1`:

   - `-loop 1`: The number `1` means **true** for *infinite looping*, i.e. for repeating your input picture “infinitely” many times to obtain next and next frame in the case of need.
2. You need to *limit the number of generated frames* (otherwise your `ffmpeg` command will run *forever*).

   As you want the 10-second video, I used the `-t 10` option to limit the number of generated frames indirectly by the duration of the target video.

   ```
   ffmpeg  -loop 1  -t 10  -i input.jpg  output.mp4
   ```
3. If you are *not* satisfied with the default framerate (25 fps), you may use the `-framerate` option, for example

   ```
   ffmpeg  -loop 1  -framerate 15  -t 10  -i input.jpg  output.mp4
   ```

Answer (score 0):

found here: https://talotics.com/post/videos/ffmpeg-add-call-to-action-image-after/

**Create a 5 second video from a png as follows:**

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 5 promo-image.mp4
```

This will create a video called {promo-image.mp4} from {image.png} with a duration of {5 seconds}